# ggplot2: Adding geom_smooth() destroys the point legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a strange issue and I can't seem to find any previous questions with a similar problem.

I have the data:

```
> econ3
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   decade [6]
  decade mean.pce mean.pop mean.uempmed mean.unemploy mean.psavert
   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>
1   1960     568.  201165.         4.52         2854.        11.2 
2   1970    1038.  214969.         6.29         5818.        11.8 
3   1980    2620.  237423.         7.2          8308.         9.30
4   1990    4924.  264777.         7.58         7566.         6.71
5   2000    8501.  294869.         9.26         8269.         4.26
6   2010   11143.  314800.        18.2         12186.         5.7
```

When I use this to make a plot, everything looks great:

```
ggplot(econ3, aes(x=decade, y=mean.uempmed, size=mean.unemploy),guide=FALSE)+
  geom_point(colour="blue", fill="lightblue", shape=21)+ 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15)+
  theme_gray()+
  labs(title = "Unemployment Level per Decade",
       subtitle = "(1967-2015)",
       caption = "Data from the US economic time series.",
       tag = "Figure 3",
       x = "Mean of Median Duration of Unemployment (Weeks)",
       y = "Decade")
```

[Plot as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab6rL.png)

However, as soon as I add a trendline using geom_smooth, the legend gets completely destroyed.

```
ggplot(econ3, aes(x=decade, y=mean.uempmed, size=mean.unemploy),guide=FALSE)+
  geom_point(colour="blue", fill="lightblue", shape=21)+ 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, formula = y~x, aes(color="lm"))+
  theme_gray()+
  labs(title = "Unemployment Level per Decade",
       subtitle = "(1967-2015)",
       caption = "Data from the US economic time series.",
       tag = "Figure 3",
       x = "Mean of Median Duration of Unemployment (Weeks)",
       y = "Decade")
```

[Plot with trendline and broken legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg39U.png)

I'm not really sure what is causing this or how to fix it. I'm sure it must be something simple.

Comment: Did you try with the argument `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_smooth`?

Comment: Well, this does fix the point legend, but then the trendline legend is removed. I could have a similar result by calculating the trendline as a separate variable, then using geom_abline(). I am trying to understand specifically what about geom_smooth breaks the point legend. Perhaps in the future I will want to add multiple regression lines, in which case a show.legend = FALSE wouldn't be viable.

Comment: Try removing `aes(color = "lm")` and instead using `color = "red"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because `size=mean.unemploy` is placed globally. If you put it in the `aes` of `ggplot`, it would affect whole `geom`. It means that the new `geom_smooth` would read the `size` argument, either.

Since the `size` is only needed for the `geom_point`, it is okay to put it in `mapping` of `_point`. You might only change that part.

```
library(tidyverse)
# your dataset
ggplot(econ3, aes(x=decade, y=mean.uempmed),guide=FALSE) + # remove size aesthetic
  geom_point(aes(size=mean.unemploy), colour="blue", fill="lightblue", shape=21) + # size aesthetic in geom_point
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, formula = y~x, aes(color="lm"))+
  theme_gray()+
  labs(title = "Unemployment Level per Decade",
       subtitle = "(1967-2015)",
       caption = "Data from the US economic time series.",
       tag = "Figure 3",
       x = "Mean of Median Duration of Unemployment (Weeks)",
       y = "Decade")
```

[image]

If you modify the **first two lines**, the legend of the points would not be touched.

Comment: This answer gives me the exact result I wanted, but more importantly it helps me better understand how ggplot works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out. It looks like the `size` argument in combination with the shape you chose makes the entire legend background the color you chose. You can rearrange and change the legend to reflect the gray color you chose. The only issue here is that you lose the blue border around the points in the legend, but I feel like you do not lose any information without it.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table2("decade mean.pce mean.pop mean.uempmed mean.unemploy mean.psavert
   1960     568.  201165.         4.52         2854.        11.2 
   1970    1038.  214969.         6.29         5818.        11.8 
   1980    2620.  237423.         7.2          8308.         9.30
   1990    4924.  264777.         7.58         7566.         6.71
   2000    8501.  294869.         9.26         8269.         4.26
   2010   11143.  314800.        18.2         12186.         5.7")


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=decade, y=mean.uempmed, size=mean.unemploy))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, aes(colour = "lm"))+
  geom_point(colour="blue", fill="lightblue", shape=21)+ 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 15)+
  theme_gray()+
  labs(title = "Unemployment Level per Decade",
       subtitle = "(1967-2015)",
       caption = "Data from the US economic time series.",
       tag = "Figure 3",
       x = "Mean of Median Duration of Unemployment (Weeks)",
       y = "Decade")+
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "grey90")))
```

[image]